# How to call ajax from an ActionLink click

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to run ajax on a actionlink click but I can't figure out why the script wont trigger on click

**HTML/Razor**

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteRecord", new { id = item.JPAppId }, new { @class = "fa fa-trash", id = "myLink" })
```

**JQuery/Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myLink").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'JPApplications/StudentIndex',
        data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
        success: function () {
            alert("Value Deleted");  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is `url: 'JPApplications/StudentIndex'`? You're not specifying the request type (GET or POST), also check if you get errors in console.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but wouldn't the ajax function run when the link is clicked either way? It's not even triggering the script in the first place

Comment: Actually nevermind, I found out that it is calling the ajax method but I am getting a error about the URL. I will see if I can correct that and see if it works

Comment: Probably the URL missed leading slash (`/`). You should try using `url: '@Url.Action("StudentIndex", "JPApplications")'` to create URL string, it will create proper URL automatically.